# Igraph - Query if vertexes contained in graph

Tags: r, dataframe, graph, igraph

I have a graph:

```
df1[c("from", "to")]

df1 <- read.table(header=T, text=" from   to
8  1949 1967
10 3273 3395")

graph_bad_edges <- graph.data.frame(df1, directed=FALSE)
```

And its list of vertices:

```
bad_v <- V(graph_bad_edges)

bad_v
+ 4/4 vertices, named:
[1] 1949 3273 1967 3395
```

I have a different graph:

```
df2 <- read.table(header=T, text=" from   to
1 1947 1948
2 1947 1949
3 1947 1967
4 1947 1968
5 1948 1949
6 1948 1967
7 1948 1968
8 1949 1968")

gg <- graph.data.frame(df2)
```

And its list of vertices:

```
new_v <- V(gg)

new_v
+ 5/5 vertices, named:
[1] 1947 1948 1949 1967 1968
```

I want to query if the vertices in graph 2 contain any of the vertices in graph 1.

I do:

```
bad_v %in% new_v
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Which is obviously bul--- wrong.

How can I do this query?

Comment: What is the structure of `bad_v` and `new_v`? The way you have written your `%in%` command means that they are vectors, which I assume is not the case - Also, FYI, your examples throw errors

Comment: @Sotos Errors fixed.

Comment: According to the documentation `V(G)` returns a vertex sequence.

Comment: see my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract and compare the names of `bad_v` and `new_v`, i.e.

```
names(bad_v) %in% names(new_v)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: *facepalm* I was just reading about `$names` too. Thank you kindly.